# Can't understand why this code doesn't compile

Tags: rust, lifetime

```rust
struct Node {
    next: Option<RefCell<Box<Node>>>
}

impl Node {
    fn print_nodes(head: &Node) {
        let mut next = Some(head);
        let next2;
        if let Some(n) = next {
            match &n.next {
                Some(n2) => {
                    next2 = n2.borrow();
                    next = Some(next2.as_ref());
                },
                _ => {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
src/main.rs:114:33
    |
109 |         let next2;
    |             ----- binding `next2` declared here
...
114 |                     next = Some(next2.as_ref());
    |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
120 |     }
    |     -
    |     |
    |     `next2` dropped here while still borrowed
    |     borrow might be used here, when `next2` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `Ref<'_, Box<Node>>`
```

I can't understand why the compiler complains "borrow might be used here". IMO, when next2 goes out of scope, the variable next is also dropped, they are in the same scope, the line 120 is the end of function, where is dangling reference occurring?

Comment: Mandatory reading: [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/).

Comment: @Jmb thanks for the link, I’m not writing link list,just can’t figure out why it not compiled.

Comment: @Jmb and that will be helpful if you could explain the error above instead just throw a link that I can google everywhere

Answer (score 1):

This is a short-sightedness of the borrow checker: the code is indeed valid, and the next-gen [Polonius](https://github.com/rust-lang/polonius) borrow checker accepts it.

However, if you want to extend the function to loop over all nodes, beware that this is impossible without recursion.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I think the reason for rejection in current compiler is because drop check?